# AOP Vs Meta-Programming

Tags: c#, metaprogramming, aop

Is there any difference between AOP and Meta-Programming?
Can we say that meta-programming techniques(IL-weaving, dynamic sub-classing etc.) are mechanisms to achieve AOP which is more about separation of cross-cutting concerns from main application code concerned with actual business requirements?

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ -- it asks a conceptual question as opposed to a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 5):

As I see it, metaprogramming is just a way to make AOP work without explicit support for it.

AOP could be implemented without metaprogramming, if your platform specifically supported it. And metaprogramming can be used for many other things than just AOP.